# Ring Modules: Constructing Examples

Tags: ring-theory, modules

So I'm trying to construct some examples of modules for a couple of rings to get an idea of what they look like, and much to my chagrin, the only modules that I've been able to come up with so far are the trivial module and copies of the rings themselves but regarding them as groups by disregarding the multiplicative ring operation.

The rings I'm looking at are the following ones (they figure in the famous McKay correspondence):

- $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy+z^n)$
- $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(z^2+x(y^2+x^n))$
- $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(z^2+x^4+y^3)$
- $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(z^2+x(y^3+x^2))$
- $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^3+z^5)$

If I could just get a start by examples of how one constructs a few non-trivial modules for $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$ for instance, that would be most awesome!

Comment: You can build a cyclic module of ring $R$ as a quotient of the regular module. Choose a generator $x \in R$. Then, the module $Rx \cong R/\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$, where $\operatorname{Ann}_R(x)$ is the *annihilator* of $x$ in $R$ consisting of all $r \in R$ such that $rx = 0$.

Comment: Since each of your rings is already a quotient of a polynomial ring $R$ by an ideal $I$, this construction amounts expanding the ideal to some ideal $J \supseteq I$ and considering the module $M \cong R/J$.

Comment: Another idea: can you think of some matrices $X, Y, Z \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ such that $XY = - Z^2$? Congratulations, you've constructed a representation of $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$, i.e. the module $\mathbb{C}^2$, where the action is defined by $x \mathbf{v} = X(\mathbf{v})$, etc.

Comment: Dear Sammy, I think that your third suggestion will definitely be the easiest, and most importantly, most fun to go about with! Surely I should be able to do the same in higher dimensions too, right? That is, find matrices $X,Y,Z$ in $\mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$, etc.?

Comment: Yes, you can write down representations of various dimensions, and the study of all such ring homomorphisms $R \to \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is *representation theory!*

Comment: One hint to make your search easier: any relation satisfied by the generators of the ring $R$ must also be satisfied by their representations as matrices. In particular, since your variables commute in the polynomial ring, so must the matrices.

Comment: And, finally, by just putting $X=60$, $Y=-15$, and $Z=30$, I've made $\mathbb{C}$ into a $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy+z^2)$-module, correct? If so, that's awesome.